# Cellular number valid in pl sql oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I want to check cellular number if it current and if true - get it in fromat 
for example 
**the numbers correct :**
0521234567
521234567 - need only to 0 in the start
052-1234567
(052)1234567
052-123-456-7
**numbers not correct:**
052123
0871234567

how I do it??
i tried to write:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('0521234567', '^0?(5[0-9])(\-)?\d{7}$', '')  FROM dual;
```

but it's return '' ;

thank.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE('0521234567', '^0?(5[0-9])(\-)?\d{7}$') 
       THEN '0521234567'
       ELSE NULL END
FROM dual;
```

If a string satisfies the format return the string, otherwise return NULL